# Multiple Comparison correction for t-tests against chance level in longitudinal analysis

Tags: mixed-model, t-test, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc

I did a memory test and calculated a "memory index" (in %) in 3 different groups, on a longitudinal scale (4 different time points):

[image: Memory index (%) of three groups on 4 time points]

I build a mixed model using LmerTest in R, and extracted the estimated marginal means (model.emmeans <- emmeans(...)) from the model using the emmeans package. Now I want to compare each measurement against chance level (50%) with a one-sided t-test, using the formula:

```
test(model.emmeans, null = 50, side = ">", adjust="sidak")
 time group   emmean   SE   df null t.ratio p.value
 1    0         67.3 4.90 3.26   50 3.531   0.1852 
 2    0         58.5 4.90 3.26   50 1.736   0.6638 
 3    0         66.4 4.91 3.27   50 3.336   0.2111 
 4    0         58.2 5.03 3.60   50 1.628   0.6913 
 1    20        68.1 5.23 4.21   50 3.457   0.1342 
 2    20        64.6 5.18 4.06   50 2.817   0.2488 
 3    20        64.2 5.12 3.89   50 2.778   0.2688 
 4    20        53.2 5.28 4.38   50 0.598   0.9835 
 1    100       72.4 6.44 9.54   50 3.485   0.0371 
 2    100       73.6 6.44 9.54   50 3.668   0.0278 
 3    100       72.2 6.44 9.54   50 3.455   0.0390 
 4    100       51.6 6.44 9.54   50 0.254   0.9979 

Degrees-of-freedom method: satterthwaite 
P value adjustment: sidak method for 12 tests 
P values are right-tailed
```

My question is, is this the correct way to correct for multiple comparisons?
Do I simply correct for all 12 comparisons, using Sidak correction (the formula above)?

Or is it reasonable to only correct for 4 comparisons in each group:

```
test(model.emmeans, null = 50, side = ">", adjust="sidak", by="group")
group = 0:
 time emmean   SE   df null t.ratio p.value
 1      67.3 4.90 3.26   50 3.531   0.0660 
 2      58.5 4.90 3.26   50 1.736   0.3046 
 3      66.4 4.91 3.27   50 3.336   0.0760 
 4      58.2 5.03 3.60   50 1.628   0.3241 

group = 20:
 time emmean   SE   df null t.ratio p.value
 1      68.1 5.23 4.21   50 3.457   0.0469 
 2      64.6 5.18 4.06   50 2.817   0.0909 
 3      64.2 5.12 3.89   50 2.778   0.0991 
 4      53.2 5.28 4.38   50 0.598   0.7453 

group = 100:
 time emmean   SE   df null t.ratio p.value
 1      72.4 6.44 9.54   50 3.485   0.0125 
 2      73.6 6.44 9.54   50 3.668   0.0093 
 3      72.2 6.44 9.54   50 3.455   0.0132 
 4      51.6 6.44 9.54   50 0.254   0.8724 

Degrees-of-freedom method: satterthwaite 
P value adjustment: sidak method for 4 tests 
P values are right-tailed
```

The reason I am asking is, because if one would do multiple comparisons using Tukey adjustment, then the correction for multiple comparisons also would only correct for each "family" of tests (e.g. tukey adjustment for a family of 3 estimates, if one would compare the groups against each other on each time point, or a family of 4 estimates, if one would compare the time points within one group):

```
pairs(model.emmeans, simple = "each")
$`simple contrasts for time`
group = 0:
 contrast estimate   SE     df t.ratio p.value
 1 - 2       8.796 6.81   3.03  1.292  0.6232 
 1 - 3       0.933 3.51 132.98  0.266  0.9934 
 1 - 4       9.121 6.89   3.19  1.323  0.6066 
 2 - 3      -7.863 6.81   3.03 -1.155  0.6880 
 2 - 4       0.325 3.66 136.59  0.089  0.9997 
 3 - 4       8.188 6.90   3.20  1.187  0.6710 

group = 20:
 contrast estimate   SE     df t.ratio p.value
 1 - 2       3.469 7.19   3.77  0.482  0.9589 
 1 - 3       3.834 4.11 135.16  0.933  0.7874 
 1 - 4      14.912 7.26   3.91  2.054  0.3079 
 2 - 3       0.365 7.12   3.62  0.051  0.9999 
 2 - 4      11.443 4.29 139.53  2.669  0.0419 
 3 - 4      11.078 7.19   3.77  1.540  0.4989 

group = 100:
 contrast estimate   SE     df t.ratio p.value
 1 - 2      -1.174 8.77   8.24 -0.134  0.9991 
 1 - 3       0.198 6.54 132.00  0.030  1.0000 
 1 - 4      20.801 8.77   8.24  2.371  0.1587 
 2 - 3       1.373 8.77   8.24  0.156  0.9985 
 2 - 4      21.976 6.54 131.97  3.359  0.0056 
 3 - 4      20.603 8.77   8.24  2.348  0.1638 
 
Degrees-of-freedom method: satterthwaite 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates 

$`simple contrasts for group`
time = 1:
 contrast estimate   SE  df t.ratio p.value
 0 - 20     -0.766 4.12 174 -0.186  0.9812 
 0 - 100    -5.132 5.59 171 -0.919  0.6292 
 20 - 100   -4.366 5.89 172 -0.741  0.7396 

time = 2:
 contrast estimate   SE  df t.ratio p.value
 0 - 20     -6.092 4.08 174 -1.491  0.2975 
 0 - 100   -15.103 5.59 171 -2.703  0.0205 
 20 - 100   -9.010 5.86 172 -1.538  0.2760 

time = 3:
 contrast estimate   SE  df t.ratio p.value
 0 - 20      2.135 4.01 173  0.533  0.8552 
 0 - 100    -5.867 5.59 171 -1.050  0.5466 
 20 - 100   -8.002 5.80 171 -1.379  0.3539 

time = 4:
 contrast estimate   SE  df t.ratio p.value
 0 - 20      5.025 4.34 176  1.158  0.4800 
 0 - 100     6.548 5.70 172  1.149  0.4854 
 20 - 100    1.523 5.94 172  0.256  0.9644 

Degrees-of-freedom method: satterthwaite 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates
```

As you see, it makes a difference for example for the 1st and 3rd measurement of the first group, one time nearly "scratching" the 0.05 level (trend for significance), which would lead me to the interpretation that with a bigger sample size, this trend might have turned significant (i.e., there is a trend towards a memory performance better than chance level).
However, when using the first correction method, these measurements have p values >0.18, where I wouldn't interprete it this way, and simply state the group did not perform better than chance level on these time points.

So, what is the more correct way here?

Best regards,
Theladur

Comment: I think either approach is defensible. It depends on what you regard as a "family" of tests. Of course, you need to report carefully what you did.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with your question, but remarkable things happen with the d.f., Why are the d.f. orders of magnitude higher comparing times 1 vs. 3, or 2 vs. 4, than any of the other time comparisons?

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. In the last day's I have read some papers about multiple comparisons in exploratory research, and thought about the whole concept again. Right now, I think I will include the sidak correction for 12 tests, but provide uncorrected p values as well, and then discuss the diverging results in the context of the papers I read (which more or less say, for exploratory research, don't correct at all; simply be clear what was done, and that the results have to be replicated in a (or better several) confirmatory studies.

Comment: The jumps in df's may be due to the setup of my model. For times 1 and 3, I used the same objects to test the memory. On times 2 and 4 I used different objects, but for these 2 times they were the same as well. As especially the 0 (control) group showed a zig-zag pattern, corresponding to the objects, I decided to include random intercepts for the objects in my mixed-model. This may explain why comparing times with the same objects have different df's than comparing different objects. Why they are so much higher though? I don't know. Must have to do with the way of calculation (sattertwhaite).